# Estimating the $L^2$ norm of convolution with $\dfrac{1}{|x|^2}$ of a function $f$ which is in $L^2\cap L^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and let $g=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \dfrac{f(x+y)}{|y|^2}dy$. Show that
$$\left \|g \right \|_{L^2}\le C\left \| f \right \|_{L^1}^{2/3} \cdot \left \| f \right \|_{L^2}^{1/3} $$
for some constant $C$.

Note that directly applying Young's convolution inequality to $g=f*\dfrac{1}{|x|^2}$ only gives a bound $\left \| g \right \|_{L^2}\le C \left \| f \right \|_{L^1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev's inequality (see e.g. E. Lieb "Functional Analysis"):
$$
\|g\|_{L^2} ≤ C\,\|f\|_{L^{5/6}}
$$
and your result then follows from Hölder's inequality.